# write data into mysql with java

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, mysql-workbench

I have made a simple class to test weather I am able to write data into my database or not

```
package climaxinvoice;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class InsertValues {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cxinvoice.invoice_list","admin","admin");
            Calendar cdr = Calendar.getInstance();
            java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(cdr.getTime().getTime());
            String query = " insert into cxinvoice.invoice_list (number, company, date, payment, quantity, subtotal_five, cgst_five, sgst_five, subtotal_twelve, cgst_twelve, sgst_twelve, total, items)" + " value (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            st.setInt(1,1);
            st.setString(2,"Climax Exclusive");
            st.setDate(3,startDate);
            st.setString(4,"CASH");
            st.setString(5,"5");
            st.setString(6,"1000");
            st.setString(7,"250");
            st.setString(8,"250");
            st.setString(9,"2000");
            st.setString(10,"750");
            st.setString(11,"750");
            st.setString(12,"3000");
            st.setString(13,"a|b|c|d");
            st.execute();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The file runs but I am unable to see any changes into my table
I am new to MySQL
Attaching a screenshot for my workbench
[workbench output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1o5g.png)

Comment: is autocommit false or true. looks like its false .. can u explicitly call connection.commit() and lt us know what happens ? that should fix this

Comment: @user641887 it didn't help

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: no error
build is successful
just I am seeing empty table in my database

Answer (score 0):

Generally autocommit is true by default.

If not use:

```
con.autocommit(true)
```

or `con.commit()`  at the end of transaction

But I don't think that this will execute perfectly:

Update the typo in your SQL query `VALUES` instead of VALUE. Make sure no other typos are there.

> insert into invoice_list (number, company, date, payment,
>   quantity, subtotal_five, cgst_five, sgst_five, subtotal_twelve,
>   cgst_twelve, sgst_twelve, total, items)" + " **VALUES**
>   (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: both at the end of my code
        st.setString(13,"a|b|c|d");
        st.execute();
        conn.commit();
        conn.close();

Comment: Did you fix the typo?

Comment: any error message? descriibe your db table as well>

Comment: descriibe your db table as well

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kNXnLLVALYNzTv3N0QsLJFO4eNnXy7cu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry totally new to this don't know how to show you my db status

Comment: remove that cxinvoice from the query. Updated query in my answer

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1epXhmKrGs2w0MaZhkSiLGB2YjKR1q9D7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: check this output

Comment: you can take my system on teamviewer?
maybe I am not able to explain

Comment: CREATE TABLE `invoice_list` (
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `payment` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subtotal_five` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cgst_five` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sgst_five` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subtotal_twelve` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cgst_twelve` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sgst_twelve` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `items` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`number`,`company`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: @sanjulgupta What I saw in your code was: You were not even calling that method

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection string, from 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cxinvoice.invoice_list' to 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cxinvoice'

Also,
Your insert statement is incorrect. Change ,' value' to 'values'.

```
    Insert into cxinvoice.invoice_list (number, company, date, payment, quantity, subtotal_five, cgst_five, sgst_five, subtotal_twelve, cgst_twelve, sgst_twelve, total, items)" + " values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: @sanjukgupta, could you accept this as correct answer?

Comment: even after correcting the typo
my problem is not solved
empty table

Comment: @sanjulgupta, you need to correct your connection string. It will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the calender class use the date class and a SimpledDateFormatter class like this and then do the insert.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: and in the getConnection  remove table name just keep the database name and in the query string remove the database name just keep the table name you have a lot errors in your code

Comment: I tried correcting the database name but didn't even work after that as well

Comment: i need to add date to database

Comment: keep the values inside the same double quotes as in insert why have you concatenated it with +

Comment: i tried with the date code as well
still not working

Answer (score 0):

> Build is successful

'Build is successful' only means that you *built* it. You haven't *executed* this *at all* yet. If you had, you would have got an exception because of the SQL syntax error at VALUE.

Comment: yes you are right
i m clicking on run file
how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble
There was some problem with drivers I guess
I added the JAR for MySQL connector to my library
and it started working
thanx everyone for the help
This question can be closed
ThankYou everyone once again